# Integral function being measurable or not

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a conditional measure $m(\cdot | \cdot)$ such that

1) $x \mapsto m(Y\mid x)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all Borel sets $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$;

2) $m(\cdot \mid x)$ is probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable function.

Define $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ as

$$ g(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} f(x,y) m( dy | x).  $$

Say if $g$ is measurable over $\mathbb{R}^n$. If not, provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there is nothing forcing the sections of $f$ to be integrable.  For example, you could take $m$ and $n$ to be $1$, $m(\cdot \mid x)$ to be uniform on $[-1,1]$ for all $x$, and $$h(y):=f(x,y):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}y^{-1},&\qquad y\ne 0,\\0,&\qquad y=0.\end{array}\right.$$  $h$ is not integrable over $[-1,1]$, so $g(x)$ is not defined and hence not measurable.

If the components of $f$ were restricted to be nonnegative and you allowed the components of $g$ to take on infinite values, the claim would be true.  If the components of $f$ can be negative, write $f$ as $f_+-f_-$.  Then, using the preceding claim, if $f$ has integrable sections (meaning that for each $x$, the function $f(x,\cdot)$ is integrable with respect to $m(\cdot\mid x)$), then $g$ is measurable.

Comment: If $f$ is not integrable, than the question is not well posed because then $g$ would be a function on the extended reals, not on just the reals.

Therefore I am still wondering on what happens for $f$ integrable.

Comment: Well, you could decompose $f$ into $f_+-f_-$, and use my remark above.

Comment: Can you please make your remark more explicit? I mean assume that $f$ is integrable, but not necessarily non-negative. Then can we claim that $g$: 1) does not take value $\infty$; 2) is measurable? Thanks, that would help me a lot!

Comment: If $f$ has integrable sections, then $g$ is finite and measurable.

Comment: What does it mean that $f$ "has integrable sections"? Can you please provide an example of integrable function which has not "integrable sections"?

Comment: I gave the definition of integrable sections above.  Whether $f$ is integrable or not will depend on the measure on ${\Bbb R}^n$.  In the problem as given now, there is no measure on ${\Bbb R}^n$.